# Segue from a tableviewcell inside a containerview doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift

Check this screenshot please

[image]

I have a tableviewcell inside a container view within tableviewcontroller. I am trying to perform a segue from this cell to a view controller. But it doesn't work for a reason. I gave a name to identifier and used this code in tableviewcontroller class

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

            if (segue.identifier == "name") {

             //some code
            }
    }
```

Comment: please give segue with controller no tableviewcell

Comment: Is your didSelectRowAtIndexPath gets called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never connect `UITableViewCell` directly to a destination view controller with Segue in Interface Builder.

Rather, create a Segue from the source `UIViewController` that contains the cell to a destination `UIViewController` of your choice.

A Segue is created by holding down `Control` button and dragging from this icon [image] in top bar of the source view controller to the destination view controller.

Then, implement `UITableViewDelegate`'s method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` with appropriate segue identifier.

Comment: xCode doesn't let me connect UITableViewController to destination

Comment: It has to. Select source controller, hold down control and drag from the top bar of that source controller to the destination view controller. By top bar, I mean from the first icon of the 3 icons that are displayed there (vc, first responder and exit).